# “Unable to load photo, an error occurred while loading a higher quality version of this photo” error message in Photos (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I’m trying to view a photo on my device but it’s incredibly low quality and has a white information button in the bottom right, which when pressed says:

> “Unable to load photo, an error occurred while loading a higher quality version of this photo”

I have plenty of storage left, I’ve tried running the Photos app with low power mode off, restarting my phone etc and nothing helps.

It’s especially frustrating as I’m sure I never set it to ‘optimise storage’ and typically the one photo it’s lost is one of my absolute favourite memories and photos of my wife. Sigh.

Is there anyway I can get this back please? Thank you

Comment: Can you visit iCloud.com and download/view the photo there? You could then send it to your phone again.

Comment: Love this idea, thanks!!! I’ll try that now

Comment: @X_841 it worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by logging into iCloud.com and downloading the photo from the website (as proposed by @X_841 in the comments).