# iPhone Couldn’t Load a Higher Quality Version of Video

Tags: iphone, icloud, video

iPhone 11 with latest iOS.

All photos and videos over a certain time period show an exclamation point and this error.

iCloud photos was enabled and "optimize iPhone storage" was selected.

There is an important difference between my situation and the one in this question:

[“Unable to load photo, an error occurred while loading a higher quality version of this photo” error message in Photos (iOS)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410938/unable-to-load-photo-an-error-occurred-while-loading-a-higher-quality-version)

In my case, the iCloud account does not show the missing video when we log into iCloud directly from another device.  It's like the iCloud account and the device are out of sync about the state of these videos.

iCloud storage is full but there would have been enough room on the device.

How did videos in iCloud get deleted without keeping a copy on the device?
Are these videos gone forever?
Where else can I look?
Is it possible to restore lower resolution copies somehow?